# RMI usage of client policy file

Tags: java, security, rmi, policy

I have a question to the following scenario: I wrote a client and a server which share two common projects and communicate with RMI and only run locally in the stage I am right now.
In the server.policy file i write:

```
grant codeBase "file:C:/webui/client/bin/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:C:/webui/common1/bin/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:C:/webui/common2/bin/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

For the client I tried
    grant codeBase "file:C:/webui/client/bin/-" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
    };

```
grant codeBase "file:C:/webui/common1/bin/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:C:/webui/common2/bin/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:C:/webui/server/bin/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

but I get AccessDenied with cryptic messages like (org.osgi.framework.ServicePermission (service.id=37) get) and (fava.io.FilePermission C:\workspaces\webui.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\webui\1310480250513.log read).
It works if I grant everything on the client side.

I do not know why, but it is possible that I did not fully understand the concept of .policy files.. ;)

Comment: The doesn't look like a proper syntax for a file URL.

Comment: I was inspired by the Apache catalina.policy file: // These permissions apply to javac
grant codeBase "file:${java.home}/lib/-" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

Answer (score 5):

Run the JVMs with -Djava.security.debug=access,failure. The output will show you what permissions are required by which security domains (i.e., essentially, codebases).